# Typescript es6 modules re-export mutable variable binding

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to re-export a variable using es6 module syntax, then change it and see the change reflected in the final import. But it is not working as expected. See the example below:

a.ts

```
export var a = 1;
export function changeA() { a = 2; }
```

b.ts

```
export * from './a';
```

c.ts

```
import { a, changeA } from './b';
console.log(a); // 1
changeA();
console.log(a); // Expected 2 but get 1
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "out"
  }
}
```

Result of run:

```
$ node out/c.js
1
1
```

I expect the final console.log to print 2 in order to reflect the update but it does not. However, if I compile the same example with babel it works. Does re-exporting mutable variable bindings not work with typescript at all or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because `b.ts`:

```
export * from './a';
```

transpiles to

```
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
__export(require('./a'));
```

and the value of variable `a` is copied and not referenced.

You can work it around this way:

**a.ts**:

```
export var a = 1;
export var deeper = {
    a: 1
};
export function changeA() {
    a = 2;
    deeper.a = 2;
}
```

**b.ts**:

```
export * from './a';
```

**c.ts**:

```
import { a, deeper, changeA } from './b';
console.log(a); // 1
changeA();
console.log(a); // Expected 2 but get 1
console.log(deeper.a); // prints 2 as expected
```

Comment: Does that mean that typescript does not fully support the ES6 module syntax? It's good to have a work-around but I would prefer to not have to prefix the variables. But if it is the only way it will work I guess I have no choice.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1215#issuecomment-168963929) it could work if the generated code was es5 specific, which I think it could be since I've set target=es5.